# What's a minimum-window alpha beta search algorithm?

Tags: search-algorithms, search-trees

I was skimming the [Deep Blue overview paper](https://archive.computerhistory.org/projects/chess/related_materials/text/5-3%20and%205-4.Deep_blue_system_overview/5-3%20and%205-4.Deep_blue_system_overview.hsu_campbell_hoane.1995.ACM.062303042.pdf) and on page 242 it says: "The search control does not really implement the regular αβ search algorithm. Rather it implements a minimum-window αβ search algorithm. This eliminates the need for value stack." I know the basics of alpha beta pruning/search, but couldn't find any reference to minimum-window αβ search algorithm online. Does the algorithm go by a different name nowadays that I might be able to look up somewhere ?